# What are the good practices of Code Writing?

Tags: performance, formatting, processing-efficiency

Writing and application in codeignitor  and willing to know what are good practices to write a code, The code designing, reuse of code. How to improve performance and reduce size of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common tips:

- Do not make functions/methods too long;
- always make a function when you want to reuse some code;
- Choose names that tell what they are;
- Use indents;
- Do not try to reduce the size of code when it becomes less readible;
- Performance: Take your time to find the best fit for crucial code;
  Crucial code: Called many times and eating your milisecs. A general method might have a lot overhead.
- Performance: Avoid remote- and systemcalls when you can do it yourself.
- Comment in code: discuss in your team;
  Using version control will make comments with date/author obsolete. Use good function names and small functions and you do not need to explain what the method does.